How to use Google Search Grounding with Dynamic Retrieval Configuration
I'm trying to use Google Search for grounding in Vertex AI with dynamic retrieval configuration, but I'm encountering issues with the Tool.from_google_search_retrieval method.
from vertexai.generative_models import Tool, grounding

tool = Tool.from_google_search_retrieval(grounding.GoogleSearchRetrieval())

responses = model.generate_content(
    prompt,
    tools=tool
    generation_config=self.generation_config
)

This works. But when I Try to set the threshold like using a dictionary explained here I encounter in an error.

The solution was solved in this issue here

Based on Generative AI on Vertex AI - API Reference - GoogleSearchRetrieval is a Tool to retrieve public web data for grounding, powered by Google. dynamic\_retrieval\_config field used to specify the dynamic retrieval configuration for the given source.
Configure by dictionary
model = genai.GenerativeModel('models/gemini-1.5-pro-002')
response = model.generate_content(
    contents="Who won Wimbledon this year?",
    tools={"google_search_retrieval": {
        "dynamic_retrieval_config": {
            "mode": "unspecified",
            "dynamic_threshold": 0.06}}})
print(response)

For a dictionary implementation, you don't have to pass in key-value pairs for mode or dynamic\_threshold. You can omit them and let the model use default values, as in the following example:
model = genai.GenerativeModel('models/gemini-1.5-pro-002')
response = model.generate_content(contents="Who won Wimbledon this year?",
                                  tools={"google_search_retrieval": {}})
print(response)

Themode and dynamic\_threshold settings let you control the behavior of dynamic retrieval, giving you additional control over when to use Grounding with Google Search.

I just explained that not works with dictionary. Not use ChatGPT to answer...
